# Question still not available after merging accounts

Tags: support

A couple of days ago I did ask [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218883/is-always-on-display-a-purely-software-feature); I was not up to adding a profile in this site because I am unlikely to return so I asked it as an unregistered user(https://android.stackexchange.com/users/310401/user310401), counting on the cookies to allow me to follow-up with the question.

Well, the cookies went AWOL and I got an answer that I wanted to accept, so I was directed towards the merge procedure to merge the accounts. I have followed it twice, clicked on the links that were sent to me by email and after clicking the last one I got a message that my accounts would be merged into user310401 profile.

Yet my profile is still the old one and the user310401 appears as unregistered and I cannot award the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: the account has been merged successfully.**

---

As a moderator, I noticed the 2 attempts of account merging, but we don't really know what is wrong with it. Only Community Managers (Stack Exchange employees) can investigate the issue further and merge the account.

Assuming that you have followed the procedure from the "Contact Us" form but failed, there is nothing else you have to do. However, we <s>will try to</s> have contacted the Community Team regarding this issue. They should be able to merge manually after verifying both accounts. Please wait patiently until then.